# what is the password for accessing apps that binded with config service in pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf

I am very new to spring boot in pivotal cloud foundry. I am able to deploy the apps and bind them to config-server. When i access the app, it is asking for login details. I tried with pivotal credentials it didn't worked. I am struggling from days to find the credentials for this. Can someone help where can i find the username and password.

I have checked VCAP_SERVICES env variable but no luck. Below is my VCAP_SERVICES

````
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "p-config-server": [
   {
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {
     "access_token_uri": "https://p-spring-cloud-services.uaa.run.pivotal.io/oau
th/token",
     "client_id": "p-config-server-066a4553-a934-4d52-b016-30e2ab7e6d90",
     "client_secret": "rHnPwJj613pP",
     "uri": "https://config-da1be911-4c82-41a3-a3bd-0b06ea295480.cfapps.io"
    },
    "instance_name": "config-server",
    "label": "p-config-server",
    "name": "config-server",
    "plan": "trial",
    "provider": null,
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "tags": [
     "configuration",
     "spring-cloud"
    ],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ],
  "p-service-registry": [
   {
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {
     "access_token_uri": "https://p-spring-cloud-services.uaa.run.pivotal.io/oau
th/token",
     "client_id": "p-service-registry-ae9f69cf-258d-45ea-821e-1fa4db37f1a3",
     "client_secret": "XJOLKHZqwssd",
     "uri": "https://eureka-89a144f4-7dc7-4b6d-8152-c4414b748ec0.cfapps.io"
    },
    "instance_name": "service-registry",
    "label": "p-service-registry",
    "name": "service-registry",
    "plan": "trial",
    "provider": null,
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "tags": [
     "eureka",
     "discovery",
     "registry",
     "spring-cloud"
    ],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ]
 }
}

{
 "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
  "application_id": "1b398fd8-61f2-47e3-875d-d3fe7574513a",
  "application_name": "customer-service",
  "application_uris": [
   "customer-service-demo.cfapps.io"
  ],
  "application_version": "d0243f11-b7af-4bb3-b3a3-b7a4c95e6298",
  "cf_api": "https://api.run.pivotal.io",
  "limits": {
   "disk": 1024,
   "fds": 16384,
   "mem": 1024
  },
  "name": "customer-service",
  "organization_id": "8e425cae-75a0-433a-a8a7-79c4f81d7c85",
  "organization_name": "MSA_springboot",
  "process_id": "1b398fd8-61f2-47e3-875d-d3fe7574513a",
  "process_type": "web",
  "space_id": "8902b90c-9964-4f9d-b426-ca1635589ebe",
  "space_name": "development",
  "uris": [
   "customer-service-demo.cfapps.io"
  ],
  "users": null,
  "version": "d0243f11-b7af-4bb3-b3a3-b7a4c95e6298"
 }
}

User-Provided:
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev

No running env variables have been set

No staging env variables have been set```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kNWC.png
````

Comment: Neither Pivotal Spring Cloud Config Server nor Pivotal Service Registry and are going to require form based login. That's likely something else in your app, probably something is triggering an auto configuration for Spring Security. I would suggest you look at the app logs (i.e. `cf logs`). In some cases, Spring Boot randomly generated creds and it prints those to the log. You can see how the app is started up in the logs. Adding `--debug` to the `JAVA_OPTS` env variable will give you more details on how the app is started up and what auto configurations are running. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello Daniel, Thanks for the response.  
I have runs the logs. I couldn't find any related details. I have added logs and code  in the github. below is the link

[link]https://github.com/ravikiran032/msa-services [link]  . Can you help me out

Comment: I am facing this login issue only when i add below dependency in pom.xml file

```<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.pivotal.spring.cloud/spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>```
i don't understand why it is causing issue

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this. SCS client does pull in some of Spring Security and this can in some cases trigger basic auth to be enabled. It seems like you're hitting something similar, maybe try the instructions here -> https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/3-1/common/service-registry/writing-client-applications.html#disable-http-basic-auth